# Can I edit the javascript in Angular from client (browser) and see the restricted routes

Tags: angular, angularjs, authentication, client, client-server

Let's say i have a login page and an home page. Only users who are successfully logged in can go to "/home".

I have a backend doing the validation.

My question is: Can the user edit the javascript in the front end where i am accepting the username and password and sending it to backend ? Like he simply removes that much code and enables the user to navigate to "/home"

Comment: The user could edit anything in theory. This is why you need validations on the backend to block that from happening, so even if they are able to bypass the login page you wont be able to see any data on the homepage since the api wil, be blocked, and/or you would also block the server from being accessed from hists that are not on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The user is able to edit the javascript on the frontend with the browser dev tool.

Therefore, to avoid hacking and make your app secured you can use the [canActive](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface and the auth guard from angular.
in addition to that, I recommend using [JWT](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/jwt-authentication-angular-9-example/#:%7E:text=A%20JWT%20token%20is%20simply,apps%20like%20sessions%20and%20cookies.) for your app authentication and navigation.

Comment: Thanks. But still I have a question. Can't the canActive or authGuard be hacked since they come in the frontend ??